# Convert PHP datetime string to MySQL datetime

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I'm trying to update my datetime field in a table with the following `PHP` datetime:

```
$datetime = date('d/m/Y H:i:s');
```

Unfortunately the datetime field in the table is `NULL`

How can I update a datetime field with `$datetime` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

right format is `Y-m-d H:i:s` anyway in your SQL query you can use `NOW()`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now

Comment: You can also instead of now() use current_timestamp in mysql query.

Answer (score 2):

```
$datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

will work. DATETIME columns must be in a **Y-m-d H:i:s** format, not **d-m-Y H:i:s**.

From the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html):

> The DATETIME type is used for values that contain both date and time
>   parts. MySQL retrieves and displays DATETIME values in 'YYYY-MM-DD
>   HH:MM:SS' format.

Answer (score 1):

The correct format is `Y-m-d H:i:s`.